# Find most repeated sub strings in array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array:

```
$myArray=array(

'hello my name is richard',
'hello my name is paul',
'hello my name is simon',
'hello it doesn\'t matter what my name is'

);
```

I need to find the sub string (min 2 words) that is repeated the most often, maybe in an array format, so my return array could look like this:

```
$return=array(

array('hello my', 3),
array('hello my name', 3),
array('hello my name is', 3),
array('my name', 4),
array('my name is', 4),
array('name is', 4),

);
```

So I can see from this array of arrays how often each string was repeated amongst all strings in the array.

Is the only way to do it like this?..

```
function repeatedSubStrings($array){

    foreach($array as $string){
        $phrases=//Split each string into maximum number of sub strings
        foreach($phrases as $phrase){
            //Then count the $phrases that are in the strings
        }
    }

}
```

I've tried a solution similar to the above but it was too slow, processing around 1000 rows per second, can anyone do it faster?

Comment: do you only need the substring repeated the most often? or do you need the count for every possible substring? these are two very different questions.

Comment: @BenLee:I really only need the substring repeated most often, but if possible then I'd like to know which was the next one.

Comment: @BenLee: The best solution is the one that will run the fastest

Comment: @RichardLivingston: This question is not answerable in its current form. To judge whether your solution or another is faster, I have to know what your solution is. 1000 rows per second is very relative, it depends on your hardware. Drop the pseudo-code, and show the *actual code* instead.

Comment: I agree with netcoder. The execution is reliant upon the size of strings in the array as well as the number of strings. 1000 rows per second is not very useful without know what's in those rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution to this might be

```
function getHighestRecurrence($strs){

  /*Storage for individual words*/
  $words = Array();

  /*Process multiple strings*/
  if(is_array($strs))
      foreach($strs as $str)
         $words = array_merge($words, explode(" ", $str));

 /*Prepare single string*/
  else
      $words = explode(" ",$strs);

  /*Array for word counters*/
  $index = Array();

  /*Aggregate word counters*/
  foreach($words as $word)

          /*Increment count or create if it doesn't exist*/
          (isset($index[$word]))? $index[$word]++ : $index[$word] = 1;


  /*Sort array hy highest value and */
  arsort($index);

  /*Return the word*/
  return key($index);
}
```

Comment: You should initialise arrays using `$index = array();` not `$index;`.

Comment: I noticed I'd missed that when I read through the post, thanks.

Comment: only solution with comments +1

Comment: @SOliver Correct me if I am wrong but from what I understand your solution provides only the most frequently occurring word, not the substring. The most frequently occurring substring is 'my name is' which occurs 4 times. Doesn't your solution return the most frequently occurring word?

Answer (score 2):

While this has a higher runtime, I think it's simpler from an implementation perspective:

```
$substrings = array();

foreach ($myArray as $str)
{
    $subArr = explode(" ", $str);
    for ($i=0;$i<count($subArr);$i++)
    {
        $substring = "";
        for ($j=$i;$j<count($subArr);$j++)
        {
            if ($i==0 && ($j==count($subArr)-1))
                break;      
            $substring = trim($substring . " " . $subArr[$j]);
            if (str_word_count($substring, 0) > 1)
            {
                if (array_key_exists($substring, $substrings))
                    $substrings[$substring]++;
                else
                    $substrings[$substring] = 1;
            }
        }
    }   
}

arsort($substrings);
print_r($substrings);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming by "substring" you really mean "substring split along word boundaries" since that's what your example shows.

In that case, assuming any maximum repeated substring will do (since there may be ties), you can always choose just a single word as a maximum repeated substring, if you think about it. For any phrase "A B", the phrases "A" and "B" individually must occur at least as often as "A B" because they both occur every time "A B" does and they may occur at other times. Therefore, a single word must be have a count that at least ties with any substring that contains that word.

So you just need to split all phrases into a set of unique words, and then just count the words and return one of the words with the highest count. This will run *way faster* than actually counting every possible substring.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes sense. What about if the minimum word length of a sub string was 2, would I then have to split the strings by all possible 2 word minimum strings?

Comment: @RichardLivingston, yes I think you'd have to split into all 2-word strings to use that comparison. I can't think of an easy way around that.

Comment: @richard, why do you keep saying "minimum"? There's never a time when the best 3 word phrase will occur more often than the best 2 word phrase, and he just explained why.

Comment: @chris: I mean that the minimum sub string would have a length of 2 words as opposed to the 1 word Ben suggested. I think Ben understood what I meant and answered as I expected, that I would need to know each combination of sub strings, rather than split by word boundery.

Comment: @RichardLivingston, I think chris meant that there is no reason to say "the minimum word length of a substring is 2". You can just say "the word length of a substring is 2". There is no way for a 3-word phrase to beat a 2-word phrase that it contains, so there is no need to say "minimum 2 words". You can just say "exactly 2 words".

Comment: So instead of splitting the string into all possible words, you'd split it into all possible 2-word combinations. (No need to calculate 3-word or more combinations)

Answer (score 0):

This should run in O(n) time

```
$twoWordPhrases = function($str) {
    $words = preg_split('#\s+#', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
    $phrases = array();
    foreach (range(0, count($words) - 2) as $offset) {
        $phrases[] = array_slice($words, $offset, 2);
    }
    return $phrases;
};
$frequencies = array();
foreach ($myArray as $str) {
    $phrases = $twoWordPhrases($str);
    foreach ($phrases as $phrase) {
        $key = join('/', $phrase);
        if (!isset($frequencies[$key])) {
            $frequencies[$key] = 0;
        }
       $frequencies[$key]++;
    }
}
print_r($frequencies);
```